# exploiting canary to buffer overflow in C

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

void login1(char * input1, char * input2) {
struct {
    char username[20];
    int canary;
    char password[20];
    char good_username[20];
    char good_password[20];
    int goodcanary;
} v;
v.canary = rand()%10000+10000;
v.goodcanary = v.canary;

if(strlen(input1) > 20) {
    printf("Username too long, existing.\n");
    exit(-1);
}

//read correct username and password
FILE * fp = fopen("password.txt", "r");
fgets(v.good_username, 20, fp);
fgets(v.good_password, 20, fp);
fclose(fp);

//remove trailing newline
v.good_username[strlen(v.good_username)-1] = '\0';
v.good_password[strlen(v.good_password)-1] = '\0';
strcpy(v.username, input1);
strcpy(v.password, input2);

//terminate strings properly for strcmp
v.username[19] = '\0';
v.password[19] = '\0';
v.good_username[19] = '\0';
v.good_password[19] = '\0';

//check canary and login success
if (v.canary != v.goodcanary) {
    printf("Stack overflow detected, exiting.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
if (strcmp(v.username, v.good_username) == 0 && strcmp(v.password, v.good_password) == 0) printf("Login successful!\n");
else printf("Login denied.\n");}
```

I've tried various lengths of usernames and passwords with no luck. I assumed I had to overflow but it always gets detected. What input of username and password would get me "Login successful" even if it wasn't the correct username and password?

Comment: Take care: With the exception of the use of C++ headers, this code is pretty much entirely C. You might get better results switching over to full C and tagging the question with C. At the very least you'll get less "Why are you not using `std::string`?" and "This is pointless. Only an idiot writes C++ code like this." noise.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The asker didn't write this, and it's deliberately written idiotically by the instructor to offer an easily exploitable bug up to the asker for them to find and exploit.

Comment: Related to:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540798/how-to-see-the-alignment-of-a-struct-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```cpp
struct {
    char username[20];
    int canary;
    char password[20];// a 60 char password can overwrite the next two members
    char good_username[20];
    char good_password[20];
    int goodcanary; // without touching this canary
}
```

The second canary is after the input password as well as the good user name and password. The length of the input password is not validated. This allows an attacker to provide an `input2` of sufficient length to overwrite both the user name and password with `strcpy(v.password, input2);` without damaging the canary.

`input2` must contain any password you want, then starting at character 20 the username provided as `input1`, and then starting at character 40 a repeat of the password you set.

It doesn't matter what you supply as `input1` so long as it exactly matches what you put in the middle of `input2`, including padding, and doesn't overflow and damage the canary.